# Floats -- appearing below immediate neighbor but not below everything

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="1 box"></div>    
    <div class="2 box"></div>
    <div class="3 box"></div>
</div>
```

I have three simple boxes. I'm using floats. I have to use floats. Here's my CSS:

```
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: blue;
}

.1 { height: 200px; }
```

What i Want is simple. I want box 3 to appear beneath box 2, but I don't want it to go completely beneath box 1, which as you can see by the CSS, is significantly taller than the other elements. The way the floats currently work, box 3 appears all the way below box 1. Is there a way to make it appear below box 2 but not as far down as the end of box 1?

Comment: Could you please share an image sample?

Comment: Something like this …? http://jsfiddle.net/PCA7M/

Comment: Not without manually tweaking it with CSS or JavaScript.  That's just the way floats work.

Comment: Along those lines, but my container is much wider than all of the box elements, so `float: right` pushes all of my elements over to the far right of the container, where I want them to stay next to the first box item with `float: left`.

Comment: then put the two right floats inside a container with float:left and fixed width